# Dynamically add (Inner) Blocks within a Custom React Component with Wordpress Gutenberg

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I am new to Wordpress Gutenberg and ReactJs (but did some projects with vuejs). I want to write a Plugin which has a Custom Block. This Block renders a React Component which is a Grid and allows to drag and resize the Grid Elements (React-Grid-Layout, see https://github.com/STRML/react-grid-layout). Now I want this Grid Elements to be InnerBlocks. The User clicks on an Add-Button in the Grid and can choose between Blocks (like RichText, Image, Slider). So basically I want to add a Block which works in the Grid React Component. I didn't came very far so some thoughts on this would be great.

My Grid React Component inside my block.js which uses ResponsiveReactGridLayout

```
const ResponsiveReactGridLayout = ReactGridLayout.WidthProvider(ReactGridLayout.Responsive);
    var el = element.createElement;

    class Grid extends React.Component {


        constructor(props) {
            super(props);
        }

        onChangeContent(newContent) {
            this.props.setAttributes({content: newContent});
        }

        render() {

            return el(
                ResponsiveReactGridLayout,
                {
                    layouts: {lg: {i: '1', x: 0, y: 0, w: 5, h: 2}},
                    measureBeforeMount: true,
                    className: "layout",
                    rowHeight: this.props.rowHeight,
                    isDragable: true,
                    isResizable: true,
                    onDrag: this.onDragging,
                    draggableHandle: '.drag-handle',
                    onDragStop: this.onMoveCard,
                    onResizeStop: this.onResizeCard,
                    margin: [20, 20]
                }, // TODO: Child Blocks
            );
        }
    }
```

Edit Function inside block.registerBlockType

```
edit: function (props) {
       return el(Grid,props);
      },
```

Comment: Hey @ico85 . I had the same idea and it would be great to bundle our energies. See [a video](https://youtu.be/njN7RMveGpw) of what I tried and achieved so far with react-grid-layout, its only an alpha version. If you want we can have a chat about it. Find my email adress on my website in my profile if you are interested.